# Android TDD of complex GUIs

Tags: android, tdd

I've Googled this extensively and all that I could come up with is the average example that using espresso I can press a button on an activity and verify that a text field has some specific text in it as a consequence.

But what if I want to use TDD to develop a complex GUI? Let's say an Activity with an AppBar+TabBar on top and a ViewPager below it with 4 different fragments hosted in it.

I really have no idea how to do TDD for such a GUI. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to use TDD for GUIs. At least not for the part that defines how everything should look. But what you should do is remove all your logic from the UI and move it to other classes. Then let your GUI inherit from an interface that defines methods for updating view content. Then in your tests you can mock the GUI using that interface and just check if the update methods were called correctly.

Comment: I thought about it but then I Google a bit and found other people who instead advocated in favor of TDD for GUIs. Although I still think TDD is not well suited for them I wanted to give it a chance.